# How to estimate age of a person using their given name?

Tags: distributions, inference

How we could infer the date of birth of a given name? How should I model this problem? Should I infer a single value describing the age itself?

Comment: I think there is some information missing from your question after the phrase "following format."

Comment: @DJE The problem was due to pre-processing the html characters `<` and `>`, which I fixed by marking the text as code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I'm immediately reminded of Bayes' Rule:

$$P(\mbox{Birthyear} | \mbox{name}) = \frac{P(\mbox{name} | \mbox{birthyear}) P(\mbox{birthyear})}{P(\mbox{name})}$$

From the data you have, you simply need to calculate the frequency of names for each year, the frequency of names overall and the frequency of births per year as a fraction of total births to compute the right hand side for any given name and birthyear.

This gives you a probability distribution for each year given a specific name, such as Michael. As for inferring which is the "most likely" birthyear, I would choose the posterior mode, because it's roughly analogous to maximum likelihood.